# How to work with pdf files using javascript in a browser? [Chrome/Firefox]

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, pdf, firefox, pdf.js

Both Chrome and Firefox can display pdf files inline in the browser (eg in an iframe).  I'd like to interact with inline pdfs from javascript in (at least) a similar way as it is possible to interact with images.  Mainly, I'd like to set event handlers (onmousemove, onclick) and display overlays (eg SVG).  Bonus if something like selecting text in the pdf is also visible to javascript (onselect), and scrolling or jumping to a different page.

Is this possible?

If it is not possible from regular javascript, would it perhaps be possible for a browser extension?

Also: How do browsers actually render pdfs under the hood?  Do they create a shadow DOM?  Do they use PDF.js or something equivalent?